# Android Development - Using a PNG as a map, marker for current location

Tags: java, android, xml, gps, zooming

I have a large PNG (around 1500 x 2000) that cut into slices and put back together using HTML because otherwise the image quality is horrible.
I want to be able to have a marker of the user's current location on this image. I'm a little lost about how to do this, especially if the image is zoomable. 
Ex: How do I make the marker have variable location on the string? (codewise)
How do I know how much to change the coordinates by when they zoom in? 
Help or code samples would be highly appreciated! I am very stuck. 
Thanks!

Note: Please be specific, I admit I am not experienced at android development

Comment: As a basis for my answer: do you understand how to do solve this problem mathematically or in another OS?

Comment: mathematically, yes, in another OS, no :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the marker position on the original image coordinates (x, y)? eg. if the user is in the middle, save their position as (750, 1000). When you zoom, everything is relative; so if you zoom to 2x, the full image would be 3000x4000, and the marker position would be (1500, 2000).

I don't see what your difficulty is :) maybe I'm underestimating what the problem is.

Comment: yes, that is the plan, I'm just not sure how to do that in code - IE variable positions on the screen.
I should have noted that I was pretty new to android development x)

Comment: Okay, my bad. I'm not an Android guy either (yet). Sorry!